# "No singleton value available for A" when A is clearly a singleton

Tags: scala, generics, scala-3, singleton-type

I can't figure out why this code wouldn't compile and fail with a:

> No singleton value available for A
> where:    A is a type variable with constraint >: ("yo" : String) and <: Singleton

```scala
case class Wrapper[A <: Singleton](a: A)(using ValueOf[A])

def test[A <: Singleton](blabla: Wrapper[A]): Unit = ()

test(Wrapper("yo"))
```

Is this expected or a bug in Scala 3?

Note that if I extract `Wrapper("yo")` then it works:

```scala
case class Wrapper[A <: Singleton](a: A)(using ValueOf[A])

def test[A <: Singleton](blabla: Wrapper[A]): Unit = ()

val value = Wrapper("yo")
test(value)
```

Comment: my bad, I fixed the examples

Comment: I forgot a type bound for the `test` method type parameter. it doesn't answer my question yet

Comment: If it works in the 2nd example, it sounds like a type inference issue. You can probably open an issue on Scala3 GitHub

Comment: @GaëlJ agreed, something wrong. I opened a bug https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/12583 thanks

Comment: Just a question, why you pass both the type and the value? :) if it is a singleton type you can get the value using `valueOf[M]` or I am wrong?

Comment: sometimes it's useful to pass a runtime value so that the compiler can infer the type. an example can be found in the last paragraph of this article https://www.epifab.solutions/2019/06/17/type-level-programming-in-scala.html

Comment: in short, if you had two types and you don't want to explicitly specify them, then you could pass a singleton value so that the second type can be inferred through a typeclass. it's a technique similar to a partially applied function

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi ^^

Comment: @FabioEpifani many thanks for your reference, I really appreciate that. Interesting point, your issue is sacrosanct :)